# Jsoup Document.baseUri() issue

Tags: jsoup

If I try to retrieve the Document.baseUri() for URL's from this domain -

http://www.deliciousmagazine.co.uk/articles/mid-week-meals

it returns http://www.deliciousmagazine.co.uk.

For other URL's, Document.baseUri() returns the entire URL.

E.g.

https://stackoverflow.com/about

will return

https://stackoverflow.com/about.

The only thing I noticed is that the HTML response returns a  tag with the following information.

```
<base href="http://www.deliciousmagazine.co.uk/" />
```

This is the only thing I can think of that is causing this issue. What if I wanted the entire URL even if this element is present? What method can I call on Document to retrieve it?

Sample Code

```
Document doc = null;
try {
   doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(doc.baseUri());
```

Comment: I looked at the source and the HTMLTreeBuilder class sets the baseUri with the href of the first <base> element it encounters in the Document. I propose another method on Document to return the URI of the Document from which the HTML was parsed. Document.getSourceUri() or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the base URI is to resolve relative URLs in the source (`<a href="/foo">`) to an absolute URL. Documents can the base URI using a meta tag; if it's not set it defaults to the fetched location.

What is the use-case that you need to get the source URL for? Don't you already know what it is (because how else did you get it)?

Comment: In the world of shortened URL's and redirects we live in, unfortunately what we start out with may not be the URL that serves up the resource. If one has to maintain a persistent index of parsed URL's and two different shortened URL's point to the same resource, how else would the developer know what the true endpoint is whilst navigating the Document object. Makes sense?

Comment: OK, makes sense. I think you could probably track the redirects happening within jsoup.connection. But having a specific document.location() property would be helpful too for convenience.

Comment: I agree. In the interim, I have taken the liberty to create a method sourceUri() on Document. I will watch out for the upcoming releases to see when such a method is made available.

Comment: You could submit a pull request to incorporate your change, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The Response object has a url() method which should give you the final url. So you could do like

```
String url = "http://t.co/i5dE1K4vSs";
Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).followRedirects(true).execute();
System.out.println(response.url());
```